# XPath for text not inside a tag?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have a very simple query but I can't figure out how to do it in XPath.

```
<p> <em>1</em> 2 </p>
```

What kind of XPath query can return just `2`? The problem is `2` is not inside any tag, making it very difficult to access.

I found that the following would work if there is no space between `<p>` and `<em>`. `p/text()`. However, once there is a single space between them, it no longer works.

Comment: A lot depends on how much the document might differ from this one. What is always the same about the document you are searching, and what is capable of varying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/p/em/following-sibling::text()
```

will select a text node whose string value is `2`, with spaces.

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(/p/em/following-sibling::text())
```

will return `2`, without the spaces.

The reason that having a space character before the `em` element causes problems for `/p/text()` is that then there are two child `text()` nodes of `p` (a   and a `2`).